# How to install orbited on Mac 10.6

Tags: python, macos, sudo, orbited, pypm

I have tried `pypm install orbited` but I still get `sudo: orbited: command not found` when running `sudo orbited` I downloaded orbited from `http://pypi.python.org/pypi/orbited/0.7.10` Where do I put the files to install? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to the directory of the files and then try running the command.